# Use .htaccess to force www AND https

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, ssl, https, http-redirect

We have a WP Multisite install with a main site and one sub site.
We just purchased UCC Certificate from Godaddy and wish to secure the entire site with https.

We are looking to:
redirect domain.com to www.domain.com
redirect http://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com

In other words, force www and https on everything..

I have tried a few modifications to our .htaccess file without success.  Seems to cause problems with Google Chrome.

Thanks in advance for any feedback or advice!

S Cranston

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(www.simplymusicteachers.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php|www.simplymusicteachers.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
```

And here is the file with the additional code added in:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(www.simplymusicteachers.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php|www.simplymusicteachers.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## force HTTPS and www. if any of them are not already present
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I found this thread and tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929623/generic-non-www-to-www-and-non-http-to-https?rq=1 , but i get the old error message in Google Chrome: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, Anubhava.  I am trying to figure out how to Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through httpd.conf .  I believe .htaccess is enabled since the file is in my root directory.  I am still trying to work out the httpd.conf part; any advice?

Comment: You left this comment at the wrong place, please leave the comment just below my answer so that I get notification. Suggest you to try out my answer and let me know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 4):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## force HTTPS and www. if any of them are not already present
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

**EDIT** If for some reason lookbehind isn't supported try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I would like to try your answer, but I am not sure the correct syntax.  I did some research and tried to figure in out, but it didn't work out.  I also failed to mention that we need to redirect the main site, domain.com to https://www.domain.com as well as sub.domain.com to https://www.sub.domain.com .  This adds a layer of complexity.  Still having issues..

Comment: Ok check the edited answer now, this will work for both `domain.com` and `sub.domain.com`

Comment: We actually need to redirect the main site, domain.com to www dot domain.com as well as sub.domain.com to www.dot sub.domain.com . This adds a layer of complexity. Still having issues..

Comment: As I already wrote, with latest edit it takes care of both these cases. I have posted it after testing it myself on my Apache.

Comment: So do I just paste your code into my .htaccess file?  I am still at a loss as far as putting the code under the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just wondering how are you having issues without even putting suggested code of mine :) Yes you need to paste the whole of it into .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT directory.

Comment: I did put in your code without success :)  I thought there might be some additional code required to make sure it was in the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory..  Maybe I am overthinking it.. will try again now.  Thanks!

Comment: No luck :( thanks for the effort.  One more try - is there any additional code that I would add to your code to specify DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess here in your question. Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled and let me know what URL did you use to test it? What is your DOCUMENT_ROOT value and where exactly did you place this .htaccess?

Comment: I used the domain with and without www - simplymusicteachers.com and www . simplymusicteachers.com.  Not sure how to determine the value of my DOCUMENT_ROOT.  The .htaccess file is in the root folder of the website.

Comment: You can run `phpinfo();` comment to check DOCUMENT_ROOT and other properties. Are you sure above .htaccess is even being used. Try putting some random text in your .htaccess and see if you get 500 internal error or not.

Comment: I added random text and did get a 500 internal error.  Pretty sure it is being used.

Comment: Ok move my suggested code to the top of your .htaccess and try again in a different browser.

Comment: Here is what I got when I made an info.php file and ran get info:_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = /var/chroot/home/content/88/9956088/html

Comment: Alright and I believe your .htaccess is at the same place. You can run `ls -l /var/chroot/home/content/88/9956088/html/.htaccsss` to verify on Linux shell.

Comment: Removed everything but your code and saved; got the error msg Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: After you saw `too many redirects` what was the final URL in the browser?

Comment: When I enter domain.com, the final url is https www. domain.com, when I enter www . domain.com, the final url is only www.  and nothing after that.

Comment: Tried that - domain.com redirects to https:// www.domain.com properly, but page doesn't load. Also, sub.domain.com redirects to https:// www.domain.com instead of https:// www.sub.domain.com  Appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Well time for me to goto bed, getting very late. As per rule above `http://sub.domain.com` is going to `https://www.sub.domain.com` (hardcoded rule now). Looks like you have some other redirections in place somewhere. If you directly enter `https://www.domain.com` and `https://www.sub.domain.com` and it doesn't work or give 404 etc then my suggested code isn't even running (since both conditions dont meet). You need to investigate your local config little bit. It could be another .htaccess somewhere or some code doing that.